# Mac OSX - how can I grab proxy configuration using Cocoa or even pure C functions?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, networking, nsurlconnection

I have noticed that my app doesn't use the proxy settings available for the machine (I'm using the [Charles proxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) to test proxy configuration). One piece of the app that makes calls using NSURLConnection correctly uses and makes requests using the proxy, the other piece of the app (that is a MonoMac app, running on Mono, obviously) does not.

It keeps making requests as if there is no proxy configured. Is there a function or object I can use to grab the same proxy configuration NSURLConnection is using?

Comment: Please check following link also:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4379156/retrieve-pac-script-using-wpad-on-osx 
Regards,
Anand Choubey

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The function that gives you all the proxy information is [SCDynamicStoreCopyProxies()](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Networking/Reference/SCDynamicStoreCopySpecific/Reference/reference.html), it can be called as in the example below (once you're done you also have to `CFRelease` all of these objects, since they're all from CF and not directly Cocoa objects):

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <SystemConfiguration/SystemConfiguration.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

  @autoreleasepool {

    CFDictionaryRef proxies = SCDynamicStoreCopyProxies(NULL);

    CFIndex count = CFDictionaryGetCount(proxies);

    NSLog(@"Number of keys is %ld", count);

    NSDictionary * proxyConfiguration = (NSDictionary*) proxies;

    for ( id key in proxyConfiguration.keyEnumerator ) {
      NSLog(@"Pair is %@ -> %@", key, [proxyConfiguration valueForKey: key]);
    }

  }
    return 0;
}
```

And the output will be something like:

```
2012-11-07 16:33:57.844 network-test[6501:403] Number of keys is 12
2012-11-07 16:33:57.847 network-test[6501:403] Pair is HTTPEnable -> 1
2012-11-07 16:33:57.848 network-test[6501:403] Pair is HTTPSProxy -> 127.0.0.1
2012-11-07 16:33:57.848 network-test[6501:403] Pair is ExceptionsList -> (
    "www.google.com"
)
2012-11-07 16:33:57.849 network-test[6501:403] Pair is HTTPSPort -> 8888
2012-11-07 16:33:57.850 network-test[6501:403] Pair is __SCOPED__ -> {
    en1 =     {
        ExceptionsList =         (
            "www.google.com"
        );
        FTPPassive = 1;
        HTTPEnable = 1;
        HTTPPort = 8888;
        HTTPProxy = "127.0.0.1";
        HTTPSEnable = 1;
        HTTPSPort = 8888;
        HTTPSProxy = "127.0.0.1";
        SOCKSEnable = 1;
        SOCKSPort = 8889;
        SOCKSProxy = "127.0.0.1";
    };
}
2012-11-07 16:33:57.850 network-test[6501:403] Pair is HTTPProxy -> 127.0.0.1
2012-11-07 16:33:57.851 network-test[6501:403] Pair is SOCKSPort -> 8889
2012-11-07 16:33:57.852 network-test[6501:403] Pair is SOCKSProxy -> 127.0.0.1
2012-11-07 16:33:57.852 network-test[6501:403] Pair is HTTPSEnable -> 1
2012-11-07 16:33:57.853 network-test[6501:403] Pair is SOCKSEnable -> 1
2012-11-07 16:33:57.853 network-test[6501:403] Pair is HTTPPort -> 8888
2012-11-07 16:33:57.854 network-test[6501:403] Pair is FTPPassive -> 1
```

Answer (score 1):

The [Proxies](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Networking/Conceptual/SystemConfigFrameworks/SC_UnderstandSchema/SC_UnderstandSchema.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001065-CH203-CHDIHDCG) Dictionary in [SystemConfiguration](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Networking/Conceptual/SystemConfigFrameworks/SC_Intro/SC_Intro.html) framework would contain this information

Comment: And how do I programmatically access this information? I can't just read the configuration file as it could be updated and I'd have to know it was updated and I can't also just load the file from the path, since it could change it's path in the future.